# Dantzig Selector, LASSO, LAD LASSO

Tags: regression, lasso

I am wondering about this. When is it best to use Dantzig Selector (the infinity normed error measure plus the L1 regularizer) , the LASSO (the mean square error measure plus the L1 regularizer), and the LAD LASSO (the error measure containing the least absolute deviation plus the L1 regularizer)? To make things clear I will quote the minimization problems solved in each:

LASSO 
$$ \min_{\beta} \left| \mathbb{y} - \mathbb{X} \boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_2 + \lambda  \left|\boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_1 $$

LAD - LASSO
$$ \min_{\beta} \left| \mathbb{y} - \mathbb{X} \boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_1 + \lambda  \left|\boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_1 $$

Dantzig Selector
$$ \min_{\beta} \left| \mathbb{X}^T( \mathbb{y} - \mathbb{X} \boldsymbol{\beta})\right|_{\infty} + \lambda  \left|\boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_1 $$

Here $\mathbb{y}$ represents the observations, $\mathbb{X}$ represents the basis functions for each observation, $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ are the regression coefficients. The subscripts indicate the choice of the norms used. $\lambda$ is a positive coefficient determined by $n$ fold cross-validation typically.

If there exists a criterion can this be determined from the dataset?

Edit: I think a more reasonable question is the following: What are the features of the fit obtained from each one of these methods. For example I am looking for something like,

the LAD-LASSO is less sensitive to outliers in contrast to the LASSO. http://hansheng.gsm.pku.edu.cn/pdf/2007/LAD-Lasso.pdf

Also please provide references if you can.

Comment: Which norm you prefer on the errors would depend on your loss function... or if you have a known error distribution, they'd correspond to Gaussian, Laplace (double exponential), and uniform MLEs.

Comment: But apriori the choice of the process generating the error would be unknown. Do we have any information from the data set that would help us identify that?

Comment: Sometimes people know, or think they know, or wish to know what would happen if they did know, that their data had some distribution. I'm not claiming that you know or don't know; that's for you to decide. If you infer a distribution from the data, you change the problem and the sampling characteristics. You may be more dealing with the 'specifying a loss-function' sort of problem.

Comment: hmmm.. I am dealing with the exact problem of specifying a loss function. What I am hunting for is intution on what are the features of each method and why one may perform better than the other.

Comment: That takes you back toward the fact that the first is ML for the Gaussian, the second for the double exponential and the third for the uniform. For a specific distribution you can compute relative efficiencies. If you're worried about outliers, essentially, the infinity norm is extremely outlier-sensitive, the 2-norm is fairly outlier sensitive and the 1-norm is relatively insensitive.

Comment: The info on outlier sensitivity is quite helpful, thanks. Any other features that I can consider other than outlier sensitivity?

Comment: All manner of other things. Those three things are not an exhaustive list of things you might minimize. Mentioned relative efficiency (ratios of variances; asymptotic and small sample), there's MSE, but also other measures of relative performance not based off the 2-norm. Or you can look at what these functions minimize without regard to some assumed distribution - if you want to minimize the worst-case error, that's the infinity-norm. If you want to minimize the average absolute error, that's the 1-norm.  Without knowing more about what you want to achieve, it's hard to give clear advice.

Comment: I am in the process of investigating which methodology would be better for a dataset that I have. That being said, I am also interested in a particular feature of the dataset that I can quantify. This feature seem to arise from outliers in the dataset, the local minimas.

I want to see which one of the methods reproduce this. Before I dive into implementation I wanted to develop intuition for these methods and hence my question.

Comment: Researcher's best answer: "It depends..." :)
Does someone know of a comparative evaluation of two or three of these methods on a specific data? I know only of [Elads Book](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-1-4419-7010-7) where several types are introduced but not compared explicitly on real data. Or is it really a simple decision like "dont use $l_\infty$ when you expect outliers"?

Comment: Oh, by the way, today I found this: http://www.select.cs.cmu.edu/projects/shotgun/supp_benchmark_lasso.pdf